# How to extract a field which has value greater than a number using AWK or SED

Tags: linux, awk, sed

Sorry for such a basic question, but I have spent hours trying to work this out! I need an awk command (or similar) that will look at a text file and output to the screen if the 12th field of each line has a value greater than or equal to x.

In this below example I would like to get number of transactions exceeded 950ms

```
INFO [tomcat-http--25] 2020-02-21 12:33:55,292 - Tranasction task has exceeded 100ms @ 1102ms for [ unique_id1:9502, unique_id2:995351, Serialnumber:514534, Txnid:70828febbb1913 ]
```

Comment: Which field is the `12th`?

Comment: 1102ms 
I am trying to capture if this value is greater than 950ms

Comment: So doesn't something simple like `awk '$12 > 950'` does not work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 3):

From `gawk` [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html#Strings-And-Numbers):

> **To force a string to be converted to a number, add zero to that**
>   **string**. A string is converted to a number by interpreting any numeric
>   prefix of the string as numerals: "2.5" converts to 2.5, "1e3"
>   converts to 1,000, and **"25fix" has a numeric value of 25. Strings that**
>   **can’t be interpreted as valid numbers convert to zero**.

So the best solution will be:

```
awk -v ms=950 '$12+0>ms+0' your_file
```

`-v ms=950`: Will pass a var named `ms` to the body of the awk program

Comment: What do those `+0` do? Note that you removed the `ms` from `$12`, so I think you have to `$12 += "ms"` before printing, right?

Comment: An explicit conversion to integers https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html#Strings-And-Numbers

Answer (score 2):

Where @JuanDiegoGodoyRobles (++) played it safe, I'm boldly going with:

```
$ awk -v ms=950ms '$12+0 > ms+0' file
```

or:

```
$ awk -v ms=666 '$12+0 > ms+0' file
```

Output:

```
INFO [tomcat-http--25] 2020-02-21 12:33:55,292 - Tranasction task has exceeded 100ms @ 1102ms for [ unique_id1:9502, unique_id2:995351, Serialnumber:514534, Txnid:70828febbb1913 ]
```